# If div value equals '1' hide another div

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I have a div that loads in the number of images on each page. For example:

```
<div class="totalimages">1</div>
<div id="arrows">NEXT</div>
```

When I have one image, i'd like to hide the #arrows div. I'm not very good with jQuery so I was wondering what the syntax would be for it to be,

> IF the .totalimages div equals '1' then HIDE the div #arrows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($(".totalimages").text() == "1") {
    $("#arrows").hide();
}
```

or in one line:

```
$("#arrows").toggle($(".totalimages").text() != "1");
```

Comment: Hey! that's exactly what I thought would work but I just tried and when .totalimages = 2 , it's still hidden. Also does it batter if it's  <span class="totalimages">?

Comment: @Laura No, it doesn't matter if it is `<span>`. Otherwise, the code should work fine. Check, maybe your `#arrows` are hidden by default.

Comment: I'm working with the supersized plugin and the actual "1" doesn't register in the HTML so the jQuery doesn't know that within .totalimages there's actually a "1". any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if($('.totalimages').html() == 1){
    $("#arrows").hide();
}​
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paw5w/15/

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you de-couple presentation from data? Using the new HTML5-attributes, you can achieve this in a neater fashion, without relying on the presentation for your scripts. This allows you to change how you display the total number of images, and still achieve the same effect, i.e. hide the arrows:

```
<div class="totalimages" data-total-images="1">1</div>
<div id="arrows">NEXT</div>

var totalImages = parseInt($('.totalimages').data('totalImages'), 10);
if(totalImages <= 1) {
  $('#arrows').hide();
}
```

As you can see, I've added a `data-`-attribute, that contains the data you are interested in. Now, you could change the text of the `totalimages`-div if you want to without breaking the script:

```
<div class="totalimages" data-total-images="15">Showing image 1 out of 15</div>
```